# imacros extract text javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

I need to get a text value from CSS element and then create a variable with that.

I could extract it with simple TAG with no JavaScript `iimPlays`, etc but I can't extract with my current code that need this:

I want to create a variable name:

```
iimSet('NAME', iimPlay(headerCode + 'TAG POS=1 SELECTOR="div.profile-info h1.member-name" BUTTON=0'));
```

Then I want to use the previously created variable from the extracted value:

```
iimSet('TITLE', title.replace(/FULLNAME/g, '{{NAME}}'));
```

Comment: Take a look at how the [iimGetExtract() function](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimGetExtract%28%29) works and apply it to your script.

Comment: @Shugar respond that and Ill mark as Valid Reply! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is unclear for me. So here's a more evident example of how to use the `iimGetExtract()` function:

```
iimPlayCode("SET !EXTRACT ace");
var name = iimGetExtract();

iimSet("NAME", name);
iimPlayCode('PROMPT "Hello, {{NAME}} !"');
```